# emrfs consistent view and command line copy/delete

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

On my cluster, I've enabled emrfs consistent view and it's working fine when running spark jobs.

However, I find tedious to manually sync/delete/import metadata after generic s3 operations.

For instance, after a copy, s3 becomes inconsistent:

```
aws s3 cp localfile1 s3://bucket/path/
emrfs sync s3://bucket/path/
emrfs diff s3://bucket/path/

BOTH | MANIFEST ONLY | S3 ONLY
DIR  bucket/path/           (BOTH)
FILE bucket/path/localfile1 (BOTH)
```

Here, localfile1 and metadata are in sync.

```
aws s3 cp localfile2 s3://bucket/path/
emrfs diff s3://bucket/path/

BOTH | MANIFEST ONLY | S3 ONLY
DIR  bucket/path/           (BOTH)
FILE bucket/path/localfile1 (BOTH)
FILE bucket/path/localfile2 (S3 ONLY)
```

Is there a way to keep metadata in sync with s3 when performing operations like that directly from the EMR cluster where consistent view is enabled?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please try the hdfs copy and see the emrfs diff. I think it will solve the problem. Emrfs consistent view is for hadoop opeartions and hadoop jobs

Answer (score 0):

Try the hdfs copy and see the emrfs diff. It will solve the problem. Emrfs consistent view is for hadoop opeartions and hadoop jobs.

`aws s3 cp`

commands will not go through hadoop.

So when we do emrfs diff on the object that are copied using aws s3 commands, they will only s3 only

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note here.
EMRFS consistent view is supposed to work only for hadoop based jobs. If one is running non-hadoop jobs, he/she will have to bring the metadata and s3 data to sync. AWS exposes aws-cli commands like delete, sync, diff, import etc. We can use these to achieve the desired result.

At times even though we are running just hadoop jobs still inconsistency creeps in. For this few things that we should check for is throttling at dynamodb end. If dynamodb is not getting throttled, look for emrfs settings in (emrfs-site.xml)

```
fs.s3.consistent.retryCount
fs.s3.consistent.retryPeriodSeconds
```

Try increasing these values and see if this helps.